# ¿Cómo publicar una página en .php por tiempo determinado?

Tags: php, apache

Necesito saber si es posible, a traves de PHP, u otro lenguaje o configuración, publicar una página (ej.: dominio.com/promociones.php) por un tiempo determinado entre dos fechas. Ej.: 2017/07/07 al 2017/07/20

Mi sitio corre en un servidor LAMP y trabajo con la versión PHP 5.6.

Comment: Lo primero se me ocurre es que guardes en una base de datos el rango de fechas que estará publicado el sitio, y en tu archivo consultes qué fecha es y la compares contra el rango, dependiendo del resultado redirijas, mandes mensaje, alerta o alguna otra indicación al usuario que el sitio ya caducó.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con `.htaccess`, puedes crear una regla que compruebe el tiempo y dependiendo del día y la hora permita el acceso o no (por ejemplo: si no se permite el acceso, se redirigiría a otra página). Esto se puede lograr usando `%{TIME}` que será una cadena con la fecha y hora (sin espacios, ni guiones, ni otros signos de puntuación).

Así podrías hacer algo como esto en `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME} <=20170705000000 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20170715000000
RewriteRule pagina1.php pagina2.php [L]
```

Lo que hace esa regla línea a línea:

- Si la fecha es menor que el 5 de julio de 2017 (`20170705000000` = `2017-07-05 00:00:00`)
- O si la fecha es mayor que el 15 de julio de 2017 (`20170715000000` = `2017-07-15 00:00:00`)
- Reescribe la página que sólo quieres mostrar temporalmente por otra página diferente (p.e. con un mensaje de error).

Efectivamente lo que se consigue con esto es que la página pagina1.php sólo esté visible entre el 5 y el 15 de julio de 2017, porque para fechas menores al 5 o mayores al 15 se mostrará la página pagina2.php.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, la verdad, htaccess es una gran ayuda para muchas funciones del sitio. TE agradezco mucho! Saludos!